# Multiple blood-type results

Tags: blood, blood-tests

What would be the reason for multiple blood-type results for one person? All taken from 2 hospitals (best hospitals in the state), doctor's offices, blood donations.

1. Blood drawn after birth (written on a card by the labor nurse) states one blood-type.
2. Blood drawn during pregnancy states a second different blood-type.
3. Blood drawn during labor states a third different blood-type.

(Blood donation showed blood-type same as second listed blood-type)

All highly reputable places. All different blood-type results. How is this possible?

All results are RH Positive. One parent is universal donor, second parent's blood-type unknown.

Comment: Clearly, at least two people made a mistake, possibly all three. Without another typing, no one has any way of knowing which were the mistakes. Knowing one parent was type O only eliminates AB as a possibility.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unanswerable.

Comment: How would mistakes be made when determining blood types in the first place?

Comment: Humans make mistakes. Most likely by someone simply transcribing lab results incorrectly or mixing up samples, and both can happen at several points in the process (collection, transport, lab, reporting results, copying results). But clearly at least two mistakes were made by different people at different times.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'd say your answer is the most likely, but I seem to very vaguely recall the possibility that with certain blood types, maternal blood can suppress features of the baby's blood or possibly the other way around. However, I can't find any evidence that this is actually so, or that it was at all related to the common ABO blood type. Could have been me mis-remembering rhesus factor problems in pregnancy.

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/58562/27148 and https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/29975/27148

Comment: There is also this https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/4894/is-it-possible-to-change-persons-blood-group/4899#4899